# Angular JS from tutorial not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, inspect-element

I just got a book on Angular JS.  I'm setting up the first project, which is very simple.  There is just one Angular element to be rendered.  I'd like to get this set up properly from the beginning, so I want to overcome this simple problem now.  The angular.js file and app.js file are in the same folder that index.html is in, for simplicity.  I downloaded the newest version of angular (1.3.2), and tried using the minimized .js file before trying this with the uncompressed.  This code is copy-pasted from the book I'm using, which was published in 2013.

index.html:

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller='HelloController'>
            <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
function HelloController($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
}
```

When index.html is opened in my browser (the latest version of Chrome), the "{{greeting.text}}" area is displayed as that string, {{greeting.text}}, not the value of the variable.  When I open the dev tools, I see that there's been an error on the controller, with it not being defined as a controller.  I know this is pretty simple stuff, but I want to have all my declarations right from the beginning so that I can learn Angular.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: go through tutorial on angular docs site

Comment: did you include angular.js and the app.js ? using <script src="..." ></script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update

Agree with @JaredReeves , so do declarr module variable like this

```
//module file 
angular.module('yourAppDep');

// Controller One File
    angular.module('yourAppDep').controller('MyCtrl', function () {
      // ...
});
```

---

Create module for you application like this, in module.js file

```
var AngularMVCApp = angular.module('AngularMVCApp', []);

AngularMVCApp.controller('HelloController', HelloController);
```

change you html like as below

```
<html ng-app="AngularMVCApp">
```

change you controller like this

```
function HelloController($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
}

// The $inject property of every controller (and pretty much every other type of 
 //object in Angular) needs to be a 
 //string array equal to the controllers arguments, only as strings
 HelloController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

You can also check basic tutorial here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par

Comment: Please note that declaring a global variable for the module is not a best practice. `angular.module()` is both a getter and a setter, thus it can be used to create angular components without setting a global variable. This helps limit the JavaScript global namespace/pollution issues in large applications, as well as limit possible conflicts in the future.

Comment: @JaredReeves - agree with you updated my answer for that

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately your original code would have worked before Angular 1.3.  In Angular 1.3 there is no longer support for global function controllers.
http://plnkr.co/edit/3BuxfWLXGqtxImsNTzWm?p=preview

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <script src="1.22_angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller='HelloController'>
            <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems weird that they show it like this. Usually you will start working with modules right away, like this:

In html

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

In js

```
angular.module("app",[])

.controller("HelloController",function ($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
});
```

I'm not sure if your notation should work as well, but this is the standard way of setting up an angular app that is used in all tutorials I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is wrong. Have a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02). It must be something like

```
yourApp.controller('HelloController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' }; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below example,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="empController">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script>
function empController($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "Tom";
    $scope.lastName = "Jerry";
}
</script>
```